# image undefined onload function, need to get height and width

Tags: javascript, image, onload

I got this code:

```
_getWidthAndHeight = (ImageURL) => { 
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(img));
      alert(this.height);
      alert(this.width);
    };
    img.src = ImageURL;
  }
```

It is supposed to load the image in google chrome, and get image height and width. Why the object returns empty?

Comment: Try with `this` instead.

Comment: How? can you post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is not pointing at what you need in arrow functions

```js
_getWidthAndHeight = (ImageURL) => { 
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function()  { // now "this" will be what you think it is
      console.log(this.height,this.width);
    };
    img.src = ImageURL;
  }
  
  _getWidthAndHeight("https://via.placeholder.com/500x400?text=500x400")
```

With arrow:

```js
_getWidthAndHeight = (ImageURL) => { 
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = (e) =>  { // now you can use e.target
      console.log(e.target.height,e.target.width);
    };
    img.src = ImageURL;
  }
  
  _getWidthAndHeight("https://via.placeholder.com/500x400?text=500x400")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using `this` inside an ES6 arrow function. It has a different context from classic JS functions. You'll have to use this code for it to work:

```
_getWidthAndHeight = (ImageURL) => { 
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
      alert(JSON.stringify(img));
      alert(this.height);
      alert(this.width);
    };
    img.src = ImageURL;
  }
```

Comment: beat you by 20 seconds. It's a dupe anyway